# paperclip attachment url ios android devices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, paperclip

On my rails server, as long as I got the model object I can easily get the url of the paperclip attachment by calling @model.avatar.url(:thumb).

However I am trying to setup a restful api service where android and iOS apps will call to retrieve these image urls.  How do I do that?  I wrote a custom call but can't seem to be able to access the url portion of the avatar after retrieving it from the database in the controller.

Thanks

Comment: Please add your model file and action in controller where you need to add the image url.

Comment: I got it working just now with: `render :inline => "<%= @image.avatar.url(:thumb) %>"` on the return line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to have the method render inline response such as:

```
render :inline => "<%= @image.avatar.url(:thumb) %>"
```